# Getting error to integrate MongoDB transaction and Update query where I use arrayFilters and opts both

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, transactions

I have used transection in my nodeJs backend and it works fine. Here is a workable code.

`await itemModel.updateOne(
    { itemCode: req.body.items[i].itemCode, isDisabled: false },
    { $push: { PiLocation: req.body.locationInfo } },
    opts(session)
);`

But facing error when I use arrayFilter in updateOne. 
Example:

```
await itemModel.updateOne(
                {
                    itemCode: req.body.items[i].itemCode,
                    isDisabled: false
                },
                {
                    $set: {
                        itemCount: prevResult.itemCount + req.body.items[i].quantity,
                        'locationList.$[i].isCounted': true,
                        'locationList.$[i].itemCount': req.body.items[i].quantity
                    }
                },
                {
                    arrayFilters: [
                        {
                            'i.binId': req.body.locationInfo.binId
                        }
                    ]
                }, opts(session)
            );
```

**opts(session) is a callback function use for transection**

opts: session => ({ session, returnOriginal: false })

Comment: Make sure you format your code correctly and describe it enough so that people can help.

Comment: What is the error?